# SQLiDataReader C# to Java ResultSet

Tags: java, c#, wcf, sqlite

Lots of people will said me it's stupid or impossible but i need to do it.

So i have a Server in C# who communicate with SQLite database. This server share some function with WCF and SOAP.

I have a software in java who communicate with the server. This java work well alone with sqldatabase but i need to comunnicate to the database with the Server.

But I need to do select with my java programme. So The think i need to do is to pass the SQLiteDataReader from C# and share it to java and java need to understand it, if possible in ResultSet or Something like HashMap.

How can i do it ? Don't said me use mysql i dont want to !

Thanks, to all people who take time to think of solution.

Comment: I think you're confusing concepts here. If you want to communicate two technologies, there are several ways. Please describe what you really need to do, not your current odd way to try to accomplish it. If the server works with C# and WCF then expose a service via SOAP or REST, then in Java consume the service using proper technology. Forget about using `ResultSet` because that interface is for database access and you don't need it.

Comment: It's Expose the service via SOAP, java consume it, but i need to share the SQLidatareader to the Java in way that it's easy to use it in Java.
Because my service(server WCF) work well for some application and my java work well alone but i need to change the sql database and pass by the WCF service.
Resultset i know that it's certainly impossible, but i thinking about hasmap but it's seem it's doesn't work or i did it not well.

Comment: If you need to update data in the database, provide a service that will do that, and let your Java client consume the service to update the data.

Comment: I need to do select.... that is the probleme the update is eas but select not ...

Comment: For `SELECT` statements use a `PreparedStatement`. Your question looks to be for someone to explain you the basics of JDBC, and that's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: ... select but it's the server who communicate with the database !!
The request is create by java, give to C# server, send to sqlite, the response is get to c# server and needed to return the result to java !!! You understand now ?

Comment: That's what I've said to you earlier. If your Java client must not communicate with your database, only the server written in C#, then expose a service to update the data from your server and let your Java client consume it. It's no rocket science and looks like you're confusing concepts.

Comment: and how you do it ? because for the java consume the c# function and get the data and get it easyli like resultset or hashmap,  i want to know how ?